# Join Query that have different results based on type of table/query used for joining

Tags: sql, ms-access

> > This puzzles me a lot and I couldn't find a reason why:  In 2010
> >     Access, I create 2 join queries. Join 1:  1 big table inner joins 1
> >     select sub query on multiple fields. One of the field is date but in
> >     number format i.e. 201701 It returns 100 records.
> >
> > Join 2:  Same big table inner join the same fields with a table. The
> >     only difference from join 1 is the second table is created from the
> >     select query from above.  It returns over 1000 records. This is the
> >     result I expect.
> >
> > I tried different approaches and found that the date field is causing
> >     the issue.  Once I remove that date field (RenewalDate), both join queries
> >     return the same result.
> >
> > SQL
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ```
> >     SELECT POLICY, Date, Val(LEGAL) AS LEGALN, REGION 
> >     INTO New_Table
> >     FROM [TABLE_A] INNER JOIN [FILTER] 
> >     ON ([TABLE_A].NETWORK = [FILTER].NETWORK) 
> >     AND ([TABLE_A].LEGAL = [Filter].LEGAL) 
> >     AND ([TABLE_A].REGION = [Filter].REGION) 
> >     AND ([TABLE_A].AF = [Filter].AF) 
> >     AND ([TABLE_A].ML = [Filter].ML) 
> >     AND ([TABLE_A].ELGIND = [Filter].ELGIND) 
> >     AND ([TABLE_A].OI = [Filter].OI) 
> >     AND ([TABLE_A].Policy = [Filter].Policy) 
> >     AND ([TABLE_A].SEGMENT = [Filter].SEGMENT) 
> >     AND ([TABLE_A].PRODTYPE = [Filter].PRODTYPE) 
> >     AND ([TABLE_A].RenewalDATE = [Filter].RenewalDATE)
> >     WHERE (([TABLE_A].ASFactor) Is Not Null) 
> >     AND (([TABLE_A].ProjMed)<>9.9999) 
> >     AND (([TABLE_A].Proj_R)<>9.9999)
> > ```
> >
> > ---
> >
> > When [Filter] is a table, the above will produce the correct result.
> >     When [Filter] is a select query, it will produce the wrong result. 
> >     Table_A is significantly larger than [Filter].  Essentially, they have
> >     a bunch of fields joining that won't show up in the query result. Only
> >     info on table a will show up.
> >
> > Can someone explain how this is possible please?

Comment: Add both queries and preferably an example of what is returning in query 2 that isn't returning in query 1.  Most likely the join conditions in query 2 are allowing dates through that are being filtered by query 1, but it's impossible to say for sure without more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your DOB fields may not have exactly the same values though they appear to have.

Instead of a join, try adding a *Where* clause:

```
Where DateValue(a.DOB) = DateValue(b.DOB)
```

or:

```
Where DateDiff("d", a.DOB, b.DOB) = 0
```